# Alter linked CSS file to remove styling for a specific HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a CSS file which provides some styles, but one of them really sucks (the `<code>` tag styling). I'd like to eliminate it, possibly through JavaScript. Is there a quick way to do this?

Edit: These elements don't need styling, and I don't need to replace the existing styling, I just need to get rid of it.

Comment: Simply overwrite the `code` to your needs...

Comment: You can't remove styles that are already set with an external stylesheet easily, but you can overwrite them : `$('code').css(styles);`

Comment: There is no need for javascript! Use the CSS cascade and you're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just altering the stylesheet and hosting a copy. Not ideal, but functional.

Answer (score 4):

You can make a *more specific* CSS declaration for `<code>`. Mileage may vary, depending on your mark-up.

```
body code {
 ... your styling ...
}
```

See: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/07/css-specificity-and-inheritance/

Comment: No effect- the original styling is still intact.

Comment: add !important to each style in the new styles. For example color:red !important;

Comment: There are no new styles. The resulting element is supposed to be unstyled.

Comment: Why not just remove the styling in the CSS sheet you said you have. And for the record EVERYTHING is styled, even if it's just a web browsers standard styling.

Comment: Because it's hosted externally, and I'd have to host it myself if I altered it. Might be the easier solution for me, personally, but the question's still open/valid.

Comment: NEVER EVER EVER USE `!important`. EVER.

Comment: For sure there is no effect! You have to reset the styles by hand. See the Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tvNUJ/

Comment: That's a rather unmaintainable solution.